# Windows 7 64 bit: Force program to use 32-bit Oracle ODBC driver (without DSN) in a Connection String

Tags: windows, oracle, connection-string, windows-7-x64

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database without using a DSN. I have the 32-bit drivers available, and I have written the following connection string within MS Access using a pass-through query (I ultimately will be using this in an Excel macro).

```
Driver={Oracle in Ora_Client_Home};
Server=
    (
        DESCRIPTION=
            (
                ADDRESS=
                    (PROTOCOL=TCP)
                    (HOST=HOST_NAME)
                    (PORT=PROPER_PORT)
            )
            (
                CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID)
            )
    );
UID=UID;PWD=PASSWORD;
```

I am getting the following error. *Invalid connection string in pass-through query.*

I think that the connection string is not using the proper driver or I am not specifying the driver to use properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any special characters in your password? What did you replace thoses TCP, HOST_NAME with?

Comment: No, there are no special characters in the password. As for the ADDRESS; PROTOCOL=TCP, HOST is a string of characters and PORT is an integer. All valid values.